# How to fix incorrect offset of Bootstrap tooltip triggered by SVG when content is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an SVG. It's very simple. I want it to trigger a tooltip. It does. However, when there's a lot of content and you scroll the page, the tooltip's offset is incorrect.

[image: incorrect tooltip offset demonstration]

---

### Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/hhsc1a4q/).

To reproduce the problem, scroll a little bit and click on the pink circle to open the tooltip. After that, click on the **bold** text and see the difference.

---

It looks like the calculated offset doesn't account for the scrolled height. I tried adding:

```
position: relative;
```

to various elements across the page, including the `body`, which is the tooltip's container. I also tried using different elements for the trigger. Nothing works. However, if the triggering element is not inside and `<svg>`, things are working fine.

**What's causing this problem and how to fix it?**

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: Nope. Ended up without tooltips. This issue exists in the Bootstrap repo, but is [closed and marked as "won't fix"](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20381#issuecomment-244818116).

Comment: Did my solution of wrapping the svg not help? Would be interesting to find out why Bootstrap doesn't like svgs in this manner..

Comment: It's a good workaround, but only if the tooltip needs to be glued to the SVG. In my case, I needed to show tooltips on various points *inside* of it. To be honest, I can't see any other way to make it work better.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess you could offset them but then you end up with lots of magic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the SVG with an inline div and then call the tooltip on that:

HTML:

```
<div class="svg-wrap" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" title="This tooltip doesn't work right.">
  <svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <g>
      <circle fill="#fac" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.svg-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/hhsc1a4q/3/